# Visualizing Time series data

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I'm trying to do some data analysis with python and pandas on a power consumption dataset.
However when I plot the data I get that stright line from `5-1-2007` to `13-1-2007`[image] but I have no missing values in my dataset which is a weird behavior as I made sure that my dataset in clean.
Anyone had similar issue? or can explain this behavior?
Thank you.

EDIT: Here is what the data looks like in that range
EDIT 2 : Here is the link to the original dataset (before cleaning) if that might help: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00235/

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you can display your dataset at least partly or to describe it more it would be easier to answer

Comment: Are you sure you have data for e.g. 2007-01-09? What values do you see when filtering the data accordingly?

Comment: @J.A I added a snippet of the data

Comment: @mcsoini yes there is no missing values

Comment: Your data looks like you have missing data and your snippet doesn't show the relevant range. Note that "missing data" in this case doesn't necessarily mean NaNs, but also jumps in the datetime column. With the information you have provided it is not possible to tell what the problem is.

Comment: How does the data between 2007-01-01 and 2007-01-15 look like? (`df[(df['Date_Time'] >= '2007-01-01 ') & (df['Date_Time'] <= '2007-01-15')]`). If no data is missing it could be that the dataset has been manipulated and the missing datapoints were interpolated (see [Interpolation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.7.0/missing_data.html#interpolation))

Answer (score 0):

How does the data between 2007-01-01 and 2007-01-15 look like? (use `df[(df['Date_Time'] >= '2007-01-01 ') & (df['Date_Time'] <= '2007-01-15')]`).

If no data is missing it could be that the dataset has been manipulated and the missing datapoints were interpolated (see [Interpolation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.7.0/missing_data.html#interpolation))

[image: Interpolated series data]

Comment: Thank you for your kind ansswer, here is what the data looks like in that range ( I edited my question)

Comment: I put the link to the original dataset also if that might help. Thank you

Comment: @onemanarmy how did you plot the data?

Answer (score 0):

Fact is that when there is data on the x (Datetime)axis, then if there is no data on the y axis,
then the rendering continues anyway. Is especially noticeable on financial data on weekends and holidays or when there are gaps.
Here this problem is described [enter link description here](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/api/date_index_formatter.html)

Although you say that the data is present, but still try this code, maybe it's a matter of omissions.
In order not to draw when there is no data for the y axis,  is used 'ticker.FuncFormatter(format_data)'.
Below I attach the code where I specifically made data gaps in the data file and a picture of how it turned out:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker


df = pd.read_csv('custom.csv',
                     index_col='DATE',
                     parse_dates=True,
                     infer_datetime_format=True)

z = df.iloc[:, 3].values
date = df.iloc[:, 0].index.date

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax = axes[0]
ax.plot(date, z)
ax.set_title("Default")
fig.autofmt_xdate()

N = len(z)
ind = np.arange(N)

def format_date(x, pos=None):
    thisind = np.clip(int(x + 0.5), 0, N - 1)
    return date[thisind].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

ax = axes[1]
ax.plot(ind, z)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))
ax.set_title("Without empty values")
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response, I think I figured out where the problem comes from; some data aren't recognized as numeric data for some reason, when i try to print the data in that range i get the following message `Empty DataFrame Columns: [Date_Time, Year, Month, Day, Hour, Time, Global_active_power]`
`Index: []`
any idea where this behavior is coming from? thank you.

Comment: Let's say you have values for today and the day after tomorrow.
Datetimeaxis will still draw the line tomorrow (the gap connects on the graph), although there are no values for tomorrow (y axis). I tried to download the file, but I don't understand which one and they take a very long time to download.Graph shows that 2007-01-07, there is definitely a problem, open the file on these dates and put a screenshot in your main message. Have you tried running my code with your data?

Comment: You can also see which columns have empty values df.isnull().any().