# How to create time_mask with two conditions in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, time

I need to plot data that starts and end at a certain time, next to this I need to exclude a period in the weekend in that time period.

How can I create a time_mask of my data that has two rules?

I already created a code for the "Start" and "End" period, but I am not able to add the rule for excluding the "Weekend period".

```
#create a time_mask
start_date       = '2022-06-30 15:26:00'
end_date         = '2022-07-11 15:30:00'
weekend_end      = '2022-07-08 14:30:00'
weekend_start    = '2022-07-11 09:50:00'

time_mask        = (df['Time'] > start_date) & (df['Time'] <= end_date)


# use only this part of the dataframe as training data

df1_train        = df1.loc[time_mask]
```

I tried to exclude the "Weekend period" with the code below, but this is not working...

```
time_mask        = ((df['Time'] > start_date) & (df['Time'] <= end_date) & ((df['Time'] < weekend_start) or (df['Time'] > weekend_end)))
```

I already solved the problem for one part. But now in my plot the period is not excluded:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8vlC.png)

[Plot in operating hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYR6b.png)

UPDATE 22-08-22

```
#%% Plot data

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['Time'], df1[Temp])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()

#%% Plot the data without empty values

N = len(df['Time'])
ind = np.arange(N)

def format_date(x, pos=None):
    thisind = np.clip(int(x + 0.5), 0, N - 1)
    return df['Time'][thisind].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(ind, df[Temp])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))
ax.set_title("Without empty values")
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[Update 22-08-22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH2zk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use '|' instead of or.
And in my opinion, you confused weekend_end with weekend_start, since the start is a later date, and the end, on the contrary, is early.
After filtering by condition:

```
(df['Time'] > start_date) & (df['Time'] <= end_date)
```

the data is again filtered by time greater than weekend_start:

```
(df['Time'] > weekend_start)
```

or time less than weekend_end:

```
(df['Time'] < weekend_end)
```

that is, the period from 2022-07-08 14:30:00 to 2022-07-11 09:50:00 is excluded.

**Now about drawing.** The fact is that the axis with dates and times is continuous. Even if there is no data in a certain period. On the left is a picture that does not remove this gap, on the right, the 'format_date' function is used to exclude this gap.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', sep=',', header=0)

start_date = '2022-06-30 15:26:00'
end_date = '2022-07-11 15:30:00'
weekend_end = '2022-07-08 14:30:00'
weekend_start = '2022-07-11 09:50:00'

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

time_mask = ((df['Timestamp'] > start_date) & (df['Timestamp'] <= end_date) & (
                (df['Timestamp'] > weekend_start) | (df['Timestamp'] < weekend_end)))

df1 = df[time_mask].copy()
df1 = df1.set_index('Timestamp')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax = axes[0]
ax.plot(df1.index, df1['Data'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
ax.set_title("Default")
fig.autofmt_xdate()

N = len(df1['Data'])
ind = np.arange(N)

def format_date(x, pos=None):
    thisind = np.clip(int(x + 0.5), 0, N - 1)
    return df1.index[thisind].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

ax = axes[1]
ax.plot(ind, df1['Data'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))
ax.set_title("Without empty values")
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Note that the 'Timestamp' column is converted to an index.

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Timestamp')
```

Below is the drawing code with a simple moving average. It's hard for me to calculate ema. You can use a library like [TA-Lib](https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/func_groups/overlap_studies.html).

```
df1['sma'] = df1['Data'].rolling(window=33).mean()

N = len(df1.index)
ind = np.arange(N)

def format_date(x, pos=None):
    thisind = np.clip(int(x + 0.5), 0, N - 1)
    return df1.index[thisind].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(ind, df1['Data'])
ax.plot(ind, df1['sma'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

also it seems correct to me, to convert strings to date time format, make them like in file:
[image]

also it seems correct to me, to convert strings to date time format, make them like in file:

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2022-06-30T15:26:00+02:00', errors='coerce')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2022-07-11T15:30:00+02:00', errors='coerce')
weekend_end = pd.to_datetime('2022-07-08T14:30:00+02:00', errors='coerce')
weekend_start = pd.to_datetime('2022-07-11T09:50:00+02:00', errors='coerce')
```

**Update 12/09/2022.**

made it more convenient to draw without gaps. Created a column from an index by converting the data to strings. In the previous version, the same principle, but here everything is done at once without a function. Also applied MaxNLocator is how many divisions to display.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', sep=',', header=0)

start_date = '2022-06-30 15:26:00'
end_date = '2022-07-11 15:30:00'
weekend_end = '2022-07-08 14:30:00'
weekend_start = '2022-07-11 09:50:00'

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

time_mask = ((df['Timestamp'] > start_date) & (df['Timestamp'] <= end_date) & (
                (df['Timestamp'] > weekend_start) | (df['Timestamp'] < weekend_end)))

df1 = df[time_mask].copy()
df1 = df1.set_index('Timestamp')
df1['string'] = df1.index.astype(str)

df1['sma'] = df1['Data'].rolling(window=33).mean()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df1['string'], df1['Data'])
ax.plot(df1['string'], df1['sma'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=5))
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Excluding the weekend period does still not work with your code...

Comment: I'll try to explain. df['Time'] > weekend_end means that time would run more if it weren't for df['Time'] < weekend_start. That is, the condition df['Time'] < weekend_start overrides df['Time'] > weekend_end, the time will always be less than weekend_start .

Comment: Okey, I understand. But is there another way to exclude that time period within the defined time_mask?

Comment: Yes it works now, but when I plot my graph, the period is still shown (as you can see in my updated text)

Comment: @ecc98 if you plot in matplotlib, then it connects the areas where there is no data, interpolating (weekends, holidays). To determine exactly, you need to display the filtered data in print and see if there are these lines. If they are not, then this is a feature of drawing. Here you can see on this topic [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71767491/visualizing-time-series-data/71771358#71771358)

Comment: I actually need to define a smooth curve and need to show the temperature per hour. Every datapoint is logged every minute. Is there a possibility to connect the number of datapoints to time? So I can plot at the end the amount of hours on the x-axis?

Comment: See in my updated message the example that I want in the plot

Comment: Why the " x+0.5 " and the " N - 1 " ?

Comment: updated answer, I can't see any difference. What goes wrong..?

Comment: df['Data'] is it a dataframe after filtering?        It will be easier if you post a file with your data.

Comment: The data that I plotted are temperature values

Comment: It doesn't give me anything. 1. The data needed to be filtered (done). 2. If there are gaps in them, then given the specifics of drawing matplotlib along the x time axis, there will be divisions where there is no data and then they will connect to form a straight line. And in general, the question was about filtering, but I went into drawing, then a lot more will be revealed. Specifically, you don’t want to answer more than one question, which puts me in a state of prostration. Have to guess what you really have.

Comment: Let's have your data in a file or something else, then I'll try to figure it out specifically.

Comment: How can I share a CSV file?

Comment: Upload it to Google and post the link here.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zvjA-MhnMExIzKkffVTjKPQ8_iwHztO5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I need to get a smooth exponential curve from after take out the "weekend period"

Comment: @ecc98 updated answer. If the answer helped, check the box below the upper and lower triangles.

Comment: @ecc98 all okey?

Comment: Yes thank you! It works! Now I did a second experiment, how can I plot both curves in one plot to see the difference between the curves (the timestamps are different)? I will share the second dataset.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TFobNQDgOGWvsqIuGu_x9taXK7dTtQLI_tSDhFlZFIY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ecc98 I think the topic has become a little overblown. The question began with one, but turned out to be more multifaceted. Create a new question (I'll try to answer it if they don't get ahead of me). And don't forget to upvote my answer, you got what you wanted?! :-)

Comment: @ecc98 made more comfortable drawing without gaps. See update.